# Generating a call graph from an Excel VBA workbook

Tags: vba, excel, call-graph

I am trying to understand some old Excel VBA code.  I would like to create a call graph to help.

Quite some time ago, in other programming languages, I had a lot of success with things like [VCG](http://www.rw.cdl.uni-saarland.de/~sander/html/gsvcg1.html), but I don't know enough about VBA to decide whether such a thing is even feasible.  And so far my results of searches like *Excel* and *graph* have been difficult to sift.  There doesn't seem to be anything here on SO associating Excel or VBA with the existing *call-graph* tag.

Comment: Isn't this a software recommendation question?

Comment: @ZevSpitz, that is a great question.  I'll think on it.  I did up-vote the first answer; maybe I shouldn't have.  Perhaps the essence of my question is "how hard would it be to create a call graph generator?"  I'll think on that.

Answer (score 2):

There are some commercial products that will do this analysis.

http://www.vbdepend.com/

But you might also consider [Rubberduck-VBA](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck). It doesn't make graphs (yet), but it does do a thorough job of analyzing your code. And it's free and open-source.

Disclaimer - I'm a contributor on Rubberduck.

Comment: Thanks!  I like what you did there with the commercial product.  I'll be taking a look at Rubberduck, as I'm prejudiced.

Comment: @DAVincent make sure you grab the 2.0.x pre-release version: there is a bit of a problem with teardown (crashes on exit), but an uncountable amount of bugs were fixed between that version and the last "stable" release (v1.4.3). Also... if you do any C#, we'll be happy to show you around the code base =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug, very interested to hear that an uncountable number of bugs have been fixed.  I don't think git can keep track of that many.  ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug (and friends?), thanks for offering to show me around the code base.  When I can devote some time to that, can I get back to you?